# Why numbers can't be used for variable's first character?

Tags: variables, compiler-construction, interpreter

I'm just wondering why most(maybe all) interpreter/compiler does not allow numeric character at the beginning of a variable?

My guess is that when a number is parsed after a white space or operator, the compiler/interpreter will treat the code as a number so that it can avoid extra step of determining what the code is/does.

So what is the real reason behind this restriction?

Comment: That rule is simply not required. What makes up a token is entirely up to the lexer. The reason most lexers use no-leading-digit rule for identifiers is (1) you don't *need* it and (2) it makes the lexer simpler and faster. In any case, the question assumes facts not in evidence.

Comment: Absolutely no valid reason for such restriction. Forth allows such identifiers, as well as many Lisp implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine a C-derived language where numbers can begin identifiers. Now compile:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int 42L = 42;
  long foo = 42L;
  /* compiler: is that a long literal or an identifier?
   * aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaargh!!!
   */
}
```

It is extremely hard to make a compiler that can figure that out.

It is, however, possible to have languages where identifiers can begin with numbers. In your average Lisp dialect, for example, the rules are very different from a C-derived language. Lisp code is made up primarily of parenthesized lists of symbols/lists, like this sample:

```
(defun foo (x y z)
  (* (+ x y) (1+ (log z)))) ; Yes, that function is named 1+
```

which, for those of you unfamiliar with Lisp, is equivalent to:

```
double foo(double x, double y, double z) {
  return (x + y) * (log(z) + 1);
}
```

Lisp identifiers can contain nearly anything. In Common Lisp (my dialect of choice), the exceptions are parentheses `(` `)`, backslashes `\`, pipes `|`, whitespace (it separates list elements), and a few others. And you can actually include them - just prefix with a backslash or surround with pipes. This is a legal Lisp identifier:

```
\\foo-|(bar)|-baz\ frobnicator
```

(Although I most definitely wouldn't use it as an identifier!)

Comment: It's simple to make up a rule to resolve that, and implement it. It's just most likely wrong, or makes the grammar even more insane.

Comment: Or to re-phrase: In C, numbers followed by strings are typed numeric literals. There have been new character sequences added in the past (e.g. LL for long long, ULL for unsigned long long). So the restriction simply reserves more characters for more types in the future.